# How to check if a location change is queued?

Tags: javascript, safari, onbeforeunload

because safari is so weird in how location changes are executed, i have some problems with correctly running some functions. this happens:

```
myFunc
   location.href = stuff
   setTimeout(myFunc2,0)

//here i would expect the beforeunload event, instead i get:
myFunc2
beforeunload
```

the problem is now, that i don't expect myFunc2 to be called at all because it is queued into the stack after the actual location change. i also tried something like this:

```
var prevLoc = location.href;
function myFunc(){
    location.href = stuff;
    setTimeout(myFunc2, 0);
}
function myFunc2(){
    if(location.href == prevLoc) return;
    //...
}
```

doesn't work either, because location.href is not `stuff`, but the location of the current page.

defineProperty, prototypechanges and other implementations are no option since location.href can't be redefined, might be because of the weird functionality for `window.location = something`

maybe an easier example, like i want to track the time a callback would take, but NOT if it changes the page (there i would close it on the next page):

```
var funcStarted = 0;
function startFunc(){
    funcStarted = Date.now();
    theFunc()
    setTimeout(endFunc, 0);
}
function theFunc(){
    window.location = "http://www.example.com";
}
//this correctly isn't executed in all browsers, except safari
function endFunc(){
    console.log("time: " + (Date.now() - funcStarted));
}
```

bottom line:
i would need something to detect if a location change has been triggered, but the onbeforeunload function is too late.

Comment: Why is it too late? What are you trying to achieve? You cannot cancel a location change. Is it always your code that changes the location?

Comment: actually it's never my code that changes it, and i don't want to cancel it. all i want to do is capture the time that whole location change took. so basically i start taking the time before the location.href is assigned, and in case the location really changes to a new page, i want to capture the time it took. so if the function to capture the endtime is called on the same page, it's of no use.

Comment: A server-side solution would be better to monitor performance. I do not think there's a reliable way to do what you want client-side, unless you are writing a browser extension.

Comment: sadly i don't have the capabilities to implement any serverside code, must be clientside only